# Unloading a DLL/Shared Object safely in a multi-threaded application

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

So I have a multi-threaded application made in C++ and the whole application is implemented using an asynchronous event processing model. The functions that the threads call are based on an id (array index) the function pointer of which is stored in an array at the index (having the value of the id) i.e., If I insert an event with id 45 into the event queue, one of the threads picks the event and calls the function whose pointer is stored at the index 45.
Now some of these functions are inside a dll/shared object that can be unloaded at any time via an event from a different id. When this happens, a call to FreeLibrary (or equivalent) is made. This leads to an application crash, which I believe is because there are threads still executing functions within the dll. So my question is, is there any way to safely unload the dll without having to worry about threads still execuing code inside the dll or it there a way to check how many threads are still executing code inside the dll?

Comment: So suppose you verify that no calls are active right now. There is no built-in way to dobthat, but suppose you have magically developed a method. You verify that, unload the DLL, and after a millisecond one of the threads makes a call to a procedure that no longer exists. How would you stop that?

Comment: Use a `shared_ptr` to the DLL's handle. Reset the shared_ptr before the call to `FreeLibrary` (or even better, FreeLibrary is called by the shared_ptr deleter). All the other threads keep a `weak_ptr` to the DLL handle and lock it before using any DLL function. If the lock fails, it means that the DLL has been freed.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you for pointing out a highly possible race condition that I missed out in the description of my question. Its not that I did not know about it, rather I was hoping there was some simple way to solve it as it appeared to me to be a very common issue in multi-threaded applications using DLLs these days. I guess that is not the case.

Comment: @sbabbi Your solution ddid occur to me but the application I am working on is performance critical and that being the case, I'm ok with waiting an arbitrary period of time to ensure that there is no thread using or about to use anything in the dll rather than take a lock for every call. It just appears to be very expensive. But thanks for the insight as I believe it will help me elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You may have an object which loads library in its constructor, unloads it in the destructor, and has a non-static member function wrapper for each symbol in the library. Then lifetime of that object will be the lifetime of the library.

Now your problem is reduced to managing an object in a multithreaded program. Probably, `shared_ptr` will fit your needs. Maybe you already have another shared object, so you could simply put the library wrapper inside that object as a data member.

Comment: This and the comment by @sbabbi appear to be very similar. But although this may wrap up the problem in a very nice Object Oriented wrapper, it doesn't appear to solve the problem in its entirety I'm getting there can still be race conditions that can break the system. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: The idea is not very object oriented actually. It relies on RAII and general C++ object lifetime rules. Of course, you always can make mistakes and have races in your program. But on the other side, it is possible to do it right. Tools like `shared_ptr` help to manage shared objects in a multithreaded program correctly, no matter what are those objects and what kind of resources they hold.